# Why is this thread example not predictable at all (outputs different result each time)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

I am trying to learn about Threads. So I came across this piece in an official book:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread Step: {0}", i); // A - see comment!!
            Thread.Sleep(0); // B 
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        t.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is supposedly the main thread.");
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
        t.Join();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Now, the book said the expected behaviour should be like this (implying the output is predictable, because threads are predictable if you know the rules and how you've configured your threads):

```
// Displays
//This is supposedly the main thread.
//Thread step: 0
//This is supposedly the main thread.
//Thread step: 1
//This is supposedly the main thread.
//Thread step: 2
//This is supposedly the main thread.
//Thread step: 3
//Thread step: 4
//Thread step: 5
//Thread step: 6
//Thread step: 7
//Thread step: 8
//Thread step: 9
//Thread step: 10
```

However, the actual results are different each time I run the console application, Why? 
And secondly, I was expecting to see "Thread Step: 0" first on the screen because A) the first thread outputs that to the console and only after that B) Thread.Sleep(0) is run which means the current thread is put to sleep for another equal-priority thread to take over if available.

```
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread Step: 0
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread Step: 1
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread Step: 2
Thread Step: 3
Thread Step: 4
Thread Step: 5
Thread Step: 6
Thread Step: 7
Thread Step: 8
Thread Step: 9
```

Run it again, get another result:

```
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread Step: 0
Thread Step: 1
Thread Step: 2
Thread Step: 3
Thread Step: 4
Thread Step: 5
Thread Step: 6
Thread Step: 7
Thread Step: 8
Thread Step: 9
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
```

And another:

```
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 0
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 1
Thread step: 2
Thread step: 3
Thread step: 4
Thread step: 5
Thread step: 6
Thread step: 7
Thread step: 8
Thread step: 9
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
```

And another:

```
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 0
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 1
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 2
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 3
Thread step: 4
Thread step: 5
Thread step: 6
Thread step: 7
Thread step: 8
Thread step: 9
```

And yet another:

```
Thread step: 0
Thread step: 1
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 2
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
This is supposedly the main thread.
Thread step: 3
Thread step: 4
Thread step: 5
Thread step: 6
Thread step: 7
Thread step: 8
Thread step: 9
```

Comment: bolov, you see a lot of times in books excerpts/pieces of code, and underneath that excerpt, the output. There was no disclaimer that in this case the output is in fact one of the possible outputs. It mentions previously that threads can be prioritised but fails to connect that idea with the example they give.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you have 2 threads in the program, one is the main thread, which is executing the main method, and another thread that is created inside this main method, and is executing ThreadMethod method. These two threads are accessing a common output, which in this case is your Console, and the OS can choose to schedule their access at any order. This is why if you run this program multiple times, each time you will get a different ordering between them. The scheduling is out of your program's control.

Answer (score 1):

I think to learn thread you need to understand how process, CPU work in computer. How they allocate/ schedule tasks.

Threads are never predictable, not sure in what sense the book is saying that, but CPU is scheduling those tasks, and never know which one starts first. You can assign priority, monitoring token..etc techniques to control some behavior within multithreading.

Also what you see on Console might be confusing but, look this way, threads run asynchronously which means lets say that if two process did `Console.WriteLine` at the same time, the cpu still need to decide which output to display first based on how CPU schedules.

Comment: In the book there is that code underneath of which they output the result, but no disclaimer that this is ONE POSSIBLE output, AND not rendered the same every time. So it mislead me. Thanks a lot Luminous.

Comment: So I understand what you say about priorities, but once the CPU decides which is prioritary, why does it "persist" in one of the threads after Thread.Sleep(0); ? Sleep(0) means: give control to the other available thread, and since we only have 2 threads,  I don't expect that it should write `Console.WriteLine("This is supposedly the main thread.");` two times in a row.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("main thread."); Thread.Sleep(0); ` I understand by this that "main thread" is outputted, control is claimed by the other thread, then returned here after the other thread is finished or relinquishes/abandons control as well.

Comment: i believe Thread.sleep(0) doesnt force give the control to other thread, instead it actually only signals other thread that I am willing to give up my turn if you would like to start you can. The only way to really strictly control the order, you need to go through token based thread model so that on the thread that has token can execute. this way you know you can control the order who gets the token to process.